# Font size is different in different browser and different OS and for different language

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

**I have 5 languages, when I change some of the languages, the font size is altering, my perfect font size is in google chrome, windows OS, and it is different in Mozilla windows, google chrome MAC OS, Mozilla MAC OS**

[image: preview of language "English" on google chrome, windows OS]

[image: preview of language "English" on Mozilla Firefox, windows OS]

[image: preview of language "Telug" on google chrome, windows OS]

[image: preview of language "Telug" on Mozilla Firefox, windows OS]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=font+size+different+browsers+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Are you sure the font-size property is changing? Can you confirm that by inspecting some text element in your browser? Please provide that information in your question.

Comment: I got a hunch that font-size is not changing, but font-family is, due to different fonts being available on different platforms, and containing different sets of characters…

Comment: Did you use @font-face to import the font?
If so, can you share it here?
(different operating systems/browsers may choose different font file types, e.g. svg in macOs, woff in chrome, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar(?) problem where English letters were bigger than Hebrew letters for some font. Since it's anyway for display purposes, I allowed myself to run a javascript on page load to fix it.

```js
var EnglishCharFixer = {

  do_body: function() {
    this.do_elem(document.body);
  },

  do_elem: function(elem) {
    var nodes = this.textNodesUnder(elem);
    this.process_text_nodes(nodes)
  },

  textNodesUnder: function(node) {
    var all = [];
    for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
      if (node.nodeType == 3) all.push(node);
      else all = all.concat(this.textNodesUnder(node));
    }
    return all;
  },

  replace_node: function(node, str) {
    var replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
    replacementNode.innerHTML = str
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, node);
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  },

  decorate_english: function(str, cls) {
    var a = []
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      var c = str.charAt(i);
      if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c == '@') {
        a.push("<span class=\"" + cls + "\">" + c + "</span>")
      } else {
        a.push(c)
      }
    }
    return a.join("")
  },

  process_text_nodes: function(nodes) {
    for (var index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
      var node = nodes[index];
      var value = node.nodeValue
      var str = this.decorate_english(value, "eng2")
      if (str != value) {
        this.replace_node(node, str)
      }
    }

  }
}

EnglishCharFixer.do_body();
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.eng2 {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello world שלום עולם
</div>
```