# RegEx - Search an entire document, pick out words that match a JSON array, and auto link them

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to produce some javascript code that will traverse an HTML document and pick out words from a JSON array, if matched the javascript would wrap the text in a `<a href='glossary/#[matched text]'>[matched text]</a>` and render to screen.

I seem to have that part semi-down, the bit where I'm falling over is how best to tell the system to ignore certain elements (i.e text already in `a`, `buttons`, `input`, element attributes...etc). I've tried to resolve this with the regex and managed to fumble along and get the following:

```
/(?<!<(a|button|submit|pre|img|svg|path|h[0-9]|.*data-ignore.*>|input\/>|textarea|pre|code))((?<!(="|data-))\btext\b(?!"))(?!<\/(a|button|submit|pre|img|svg|path|h[0-9])>)/gi
```

*(**text** is the word I'm trying to auto-link)* - https://regex101.com/r/u7cLPR/1

If you follow the Regex101 link you'll see I "think" I've managed to cover all bases bar one  which is when the word occurs in a `class=''` tag (and therefore others like style and such)

Any help here would be greatly appreciated here, as always with Regex I always seem to miss the mark or over-complicate the solution, (is Regex even the right tool for the job here?)

Comment: You might want to try something like [`cheerio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) for more maintainable code and not a giant regular expression

Comment: regexp is definitely wrong for html because the latter is nested and complicated. use DOMParser or iterate the elements using dom methods. can you share an example of input and output?

Comment: @ITgoldman - it's really hard to give just one example I suppose as the idea is to drop this on any page and auto-link words/phrases for a glossary-type system.

but if you wanted something I've been playing with this is the sandbox I've been playing with - https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-f157y9?file=/index.html

If I was to traverse the dom or nodes? Wouldn't that be harder? As I'd be going down the route of in one loop "node (and its descendants)" than "direct descendants (and its descendants) ...etc so wouldn't that cause more issues?

Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be recursive and quite fast. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855865/3807365) about changing size of English letters in all text nodes - It's the same idea.

```js
var words = ["text", "one"]
var skip_elements = ["BUTTON", "TEXTAREA"]

var EnglishCharFixer = {

  do_elem: function(elem) {
    var nodes = this.textNodesUnder(elem);
    this.process_text_nodes(nodes)
  },

  textNodesUnder: function(node) {
    var all = [];
    for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
      if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        all.push(node);
      } else {
        if (skip_elements.indexOf(node.tagName) == -1) {
          all = all.concat(this.textNodesUnder(node));
        }
      }
    }
    return all;
  },

  replace_node: function(node, str) {
    var replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
    replacementNode.innerHTML = str
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, node);
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  },

  do_text: function(str) {
  
    // improve this function please
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      str = str.replace(word, '<a href="glossary/#' + word + '">' + word + "</a>");
    })
    return str;
  },

  process_text_nodes: function(nodes) {
    for (var index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
      var node = nodes[index];
      var value = node.nodeValue
      var str = this.do_text(value)
      if (str != value) {
        this.replace_node(node, str)
      }
    }
  }
  
}


EnglishCharFixer.do_elem(document.body);
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>some title with text</h1>
  <button>text shouldn't change</button> just a text node
  <div style="padding:30px">
    <p>paragraph with text</p>
    another one
    <br>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" title="this text shouldn't change as well">
  </div>
  <textarea>hello text</textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Okay, I understand now this is a brilliant suggestion and looking through this should work a treat.

I'm thinking it might be best to have an allow list vs a disallow list (I know I had it as disallow) but the approach you take makes me release there are far more nodes you don't want than do!