# How to replace all of a certain string in html while keeping javascript attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace a part of an HTML document using RegEx.

Take this example:

```js
for (; document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(/ea/) != -1;) {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/ea/, "x");
}
```

```html
I eat food and read books.
```

But how would I replace part of the HTML tag (root element) and not remove anything?
(event listeners, etc)?

```js
function x(e) {
return document.querySelector(e);
}
x("textarea").value = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
x("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
console.log("button pressed");
for (; document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(/the-language/) != -1;) {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/the-language/, "x");
}
x("textarea").value = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="the-language">
<p>the-language</p>
<p>There is a button with an event listener, and the HTML tag has the word I'm replacing. The event listener is removed and the root element (html) isn't changed.</p>
<button>Click me to replace and then show new content in textarea</button>
<p>the-language</p>
<textarea></textarea>
</html>
```

Comment: you can easily put new innerHTML equal the element innerHTML. 
element.innerHTML= new_html;

Comment: You might look at `document.createTreeWalker()`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this string replacement?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the attribute using `setAttribute` of course. You can:

```js
document.querySelector("html").setAttribute('lang', 'other-lang');
```

Other than that, check out my recent answer about changing only *text* nodes. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73776244/regex-search-an-entire-document-pick-out-words-that-match-a-json-array-and-a/73779610#73779610)